# BeautifulSoup cant find existing tag also returning wrong tag

Tags: iframe, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, mt4

The code I've got now cant even find the span text i'm looking for.

```
    import bs4
        from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


        my_url = 'https://mt4webtrader.fxpro.com/'

        uClient = uReq(my_url)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()
        page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
        content = page_soup.findAll("span",{"class":"content"})
        print(content)

    == RESTART: C:/Users/vinny/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/fxpromt4.py ==
    []
    >>>
```

the above is what im really trying to find, so I tried to go another route

```
    import bs4
        from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


        my_url = 'https://mt4webtrader.fxpro.com/'

        uClient = uReq(my_url)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()
        page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
        content = page_soup.body
        print(content)
== RESTART: C:/Users/vinny/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/fxpromt4.py ==
<body style="height:100%">
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe height="0" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-W2HBQG" style="display:none;visibility:hidden" width="0"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<section class="header-webterminal">
<div class="header-webterminal-block">
<a class="header-webterminal-logo" href="">
<img alt="FxPro" src="images/logo.png"/>
</a>
</div>
<div class="header-webterminal-block center">
<div class="header-webterminal-title">MetaTrader 4 Web Terminal</div>
</div>
<div class="header-webterminal-block">
<ul class="header-webterminal-list">
<li><a class="login" href="https://direct.fxpro.group/en/login" target="_blank">Login / Register</a></li>
<li><a class="funds" href="https://direct.fxpro.group/en/wallet/deposit" target="_blank">Fund Now</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</section>
<iframe allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" src="https://trade.mql5.com/trade?servers=FxPro.com-Demo01%2cFxPro.com-Demo04%2cFxPro.com-Demo05%2cFxPro.com-Demo06%2cFxPro.com-Real01%2cFxPro.com-Real02%2cFxPro.com-Real03%2cFxPro.com-Real04%2cFxPro.com-Real05%2cFxPro.com-Real06%2cFxPro.com-Real07&amp;trade_server=FxPro.com-Demo01&amp;demo_server=FxPro.com-Demo01&amp;startup_mode=open_demo&amp;lang=en" style="width: 100%; height: 95%; border: none"></iframe>
</body>
>>>
```

now to get to the next tag #iframe I get the following wrong tag

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uRe
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


my_url = 'https://mt4webtrader.fxpro.com/'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
content = page_soup.iframe
print(content)
 == RESTART: C:/Users/vinny/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/fxpromt4.py ==
<iframe height="0" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-W2HBQG" style="display:none;visibility:hidden" width="0"></iframe>
>>>
```

what I really want from this code is to just call the "span" class="content" tag on the mt4 page

ive followed every youtube video out there about web parsing but I just cant seem to get passed this problem

Comment: Check the source HTML - you'll probably find that all the content is generated by javascript hence your span isn't there for beautifulsoup to parse...

Comment: how to I get the information from the table in python though?

Comment: You'll either have to automate a browser using selenium, try using [`requests-html`](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) and get that to attempt to run the javascript or reverse engineer the javascript and/or use your browser development tools to see if there's end points you can emulate using plain requests to get the data that's used to build the table... I'm afraid all of those are fairly involved and not really suitable for the Stack Overflow Q&A format.

Comment: I can extract the information in the table, in the console of the developer tools in my browser. how can I call on this information in python?

Comment: Look at the options I've mentioned above...